# Getting error Error: The given key was not present in the dictionary. in production

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, web-services, iis

I am using ASP.Net 4.0 w/ a C# Web service. This also utilizes a C# library, which is working fine in development and with other applications (Skype bot and Windows form)

I am using JQuery to communicate via JSON to the web service. In development, this is working fine. In production, it is partly working. I can use some commands, but other commands simply throw this error:

```
Error: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
```

I am not certain where to begin with this. I can't step through code because it only happens in prod. I checked the IIS logs, and every request is getting a 200 status, so it appears it is something inside of the app itself. Any ideas where to start with this?

Comment: Could be lots of things. Depends on how the dictionary is getting populated. If it's getting populated from a DB and you use a different DB for production, that could be your issue. As @SLaks said, the stack trace would help, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was using WebClient to call a URL that required a Login. I setup my app pool w/ my domain creds and then I was able to call the page w/o being prompted for a login.

Once calling the page, I was able to populate a list and loop through it. The error above was thrown because I was looping through an empty list.

Answer (score 5):

The error suggests that the server-side code is attempting to access a dictionary with a key that is not in that dictionary.

I suggest modifying the code to place error handling around all dictionary access.  When handling the error, log the key that was attempted to be read from the dictionary.

When logging exception details, it is wise to log all available information.

```
Exception.ToString()
```

accomplishes just that.

Comment: Calling `Exception.ToString()` is probably better: it gives you all of the above information, and in some cases more (e.g. `FileNotFoundException` includes FusionLog where appropriate).

Comment: I added error checking. I put try-catches around every block of code, but no exceptions are being thrown.

Comment: @Sugitime: I guarantee that an exception is being thrown somewhere if you are getting that message.

Comment: Yeah you have to be right. Ok I'll keep looking into where that message is coming from.

Comment: Ok so I updated the DLL, but for some reason, the app is still using the old DLL. The DLL is not registered on the server. Even if I delete the DLL and try to run a command that uses it, the command still processes (then throws the error). Any ideas how to decache this DLL?

Answer (score 1):

You can delete all queue message from sqlsrver Queue you are using as ,

```
declare @c uniqueidentifier
while(1=1)
begin
    select top 1 @c = conversation_handle from dbo.yourqueuenqme
    if (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
    break
    end conversation @c with cleanup
end
```

It will work after that .